# Recursive population of required csv fields

Tags: python, csv

Here is the Puzzle

Starting with the following data set (csv)

```
ID,PARENTID,FNID
100,,100
102,100,
103,102,
104,102,
105,103,
106,105,
200,,200
202,200,
203,202,
204,202,
205,203,
206,205,
```

This creates two hierarchical trees that look roughly like this

```
                       100
                       /  
                      102
                     /   \
                   103   104
                  /
                 105
                /
               106
```

As shown the source data has three columns.  ID is the primary key and must be a unique value. PARENTID is what defines the relationships in the tree.  FNID is a required field used by the application that ingests all of this data and indicates the ROOT element of each tree.

In the source data the FNID field is not populated, save for the ROOT element itself.

Logically I imagine a process where if FNID is null, the process looks at the FNID field for the record of the PARENTID.

example:  FNID for element 102 is null.  Script identifies the PARENTID of element 102 as 100.  Script then looks at the FNID for element 100 and finds a value which is then populated into the FNID field for element 102.

The trick here is that these datasets are not necessarily going to be in a convenient order and could be rather large (>100k records).

Any ideas on how to pull this off?
So far my manipulation of the source csv data has been using python, but I am open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few ways to tackle this, I guess.

Easiest would probably to read the file row by row and for each row, add a node or an edge to a graph object (such as the `DiGraph` class in the `NetworkX` package):

If the row has an FNID id, just add the node.
If the row doesn't but has a "parent" id, add an edge from ID to PARENTID (and of course add the end nodes if they aren't in the graph already).

Once you've so ingested every row, you can now ask `NetworkX` to give you the connected components of the graph.

Each of those components will be a tree, and you can then use NetworkX to tell you what the root of the tree is. Then when you want to know the correct FNID for a particular node, you just need to know which connected component it belongs to.

If the actual parent child network details don't matter and it only matters what the roots of the trees are, there might be some simplification possible with disjoin-set data structures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: That looks like a plausible path forward.  As I am fairly new to to this, could I get a sample code snippet for the main actions (add node, add edge, query for graph start)?

Comment: For that, I will kindly refer you to the networkx tutorial: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html